# Pandas: Only the last row is appearing

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

While the definitions of both tissue and tube can be seen using the print function, only tube shows up in pandas.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
from requests import get
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def get_soup(url):
    soup = bs(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    return soup.select("#MainTxt")[0].select('.ds-single')[0].text.strip()

def lookup(word):
    base_url  = "http://www.thefreedictionary.com/"
    query_url = base_url + word
    return get_soup(query_url)

Terms = ["Tissues", "tube"]

for i in Terms:
    m = lookup(i)
    r = print("Word:" + " " + i + " | " + m)
    data = {'Word':[i],'Definition':[m]}
    print("\n")
 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[image]

Comment: Dictionary keys are unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generating but not storing the values of `data`, so python doesn't keep all previously generated values except the last, to overcome this, you can store all generated values in a list:

```
Terms = ["Tissues", "tube"]
data = []
for i in Terms:
    m = lookup(i)
    r = print("Word:" + " " + i + " | " + m)
    data.append({'Word':[i],'Definition':[m]})
    print("\n")

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the following line

```py
data = {'Word':[i],'Definition':[m]}
```

you are overwriting your dictionary i.e. the `data` variable, because of that your dataframe contains only one rows, you can rather create two empty list for Word and Definition by keeping the respective terms as keys of the dictionary and then append the values in them.

The modified code would look something like this

```py
data = {'Word': [], 'Definition': []}
for i in Terms:
    m = lookup(i)
    r = print("Word:" + " " + i + " | " + m)
    data['Word'].append(i)
    data['Definition'].append(m)
    print("\n")
```